# Line graph with first half, second half year x-axis?

Tags: stata

I have 2 observations per year for years 2011-2015. The first observation is january-june and the second is july-december. To preserve the year I thought I should make a variable that denotes if that observation is a "half" or not. But now I'm not sure how to graph it...

```
year    half    value
2011    0       10.42
2011    1       10.33
2012    0       11.66
2012    1       11.01
2013    0       14.29
2013    1       10.95
2014    0       12.42
2014    1       7.04
2015    0       7.07
2015    1       6.95
```

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you tried? What kind of graph exactly do you seek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to plot such data. Here's one:

```
clear 
input year    half    value
2011    0       10.42
2011    1       10.33
2012    0       11.66
2012    1       11.01
2013    0       14.29
2013    1       10.95
2014    0       12.42
2014    1       7.04
2015    0       7.07
2015    1       6.95
end 

set scheme s1color 

gen date  = yh(year, half + 1) 
format date %th 

twoway line value date, ///
|| scatter value date if half == 0, ms(Oh) || scatter value date if half == 1 , ms(Th) ///
legend(order(2 "Jan-June" 3 "Jul-Dec") ring(0) col(1) pos(1)) xtitle("")
```

[image]